# How to read custom formatted dates as timestamp in pyspark

Tags: csv, apache-spark, date-formatting, azure-databricks

I want to use spark.read() to pull data from a .csv file, while enforcing a schema. However, I can't get spark to recognize my dates as timestamps.

First I create a dummy file to test with

```
%scala
Seq("1|1/15/2019 2:24:00 AM","2|test","3|").toDF().write.text("/tmp/input/csvDateReadTest")
```

Then I try to read it, and provide a dateFormat string, but it doesn't recognize my dates, and sends the records to the badRecordsPath

```
df = spark.read.format('csv')
               .schema("id int, dt timestamp")
               .option("delimiter","|")
               .option("badRecordsPath","/tmp/badRecordsPath")
               .option("dateFormat","M/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss aaa")
               .load("/tmp/input/csvDateReadTest")
```

As the result, I get just 1 record in df (ID 3), when I'm expecting to see 2. (IDs 1 and 3)

```
df.show()

+---+----+
| id|  dt|
+---+----+
|  3|null|
+---+----+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must change the `dateFormat` to `timestampFormat` since in your case you need a timestamp type and not a date. Additionally the value of timestamp format should be `mm/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss a`.

Sample data:

```
Seq(
"1|1/15/2019 2:24:00 AM",
"2|test",
"3|5/30/1981 3:11:00 PM"
).toDF().write.text("/tmp/input/csvDateReadTest")
```

With the changes for the timestamp:

```
val df = spark.read.format("csv")
               .schema("id int, dt timestamp")
               .option("delimiter","|")
               .option("badRecordsPath","/tmp/badRecordsPath")
               .option("timestampFormat","mm/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss a")
               .load("/tmp/input/csvDateReadTest")
```

And the output:

```
+----+-------------------+
|  id|                 dt|
+----+-------------------+
|   1|2019-01-15 02:24:00|
|   3|1981-01-30 15:11:00|
|null|               null|
+----+-------------------+
```

Note that the record with id 2 failed to comply with the schema definition and therefore it will contain `null`. If you want to keep also the invalid records you need to change the timestamp column into string and the output in this case will be:

```
+---+--------------------+
| id|                  dt|
+---+--------------------+
|  1|1/15/2019 2:24:00 AM|
|  3|5/30/1981 3:11:00 PM|
|  2|                test|
+---+--------------------+
```

**UPDATE:**

In order to change the string dt into timestamp type you could try with `df.withColumn("dt", $"dt".cast("timestamp"))` although this will fail and replace all the values with null.

You can achieve this with the next code:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.util.{Date, Locale} 
import java.sql.Timestamp
import scala.util.{Try, Success, Failure}

val formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("mm/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss a", Locale.US)
df.map{ case Row(id:Int, dt:String) =>
    val tryParse = Try[Date](formatter.parse(dt))

    val p_timestamp = tryParse match {
        case Success(parsed) => new Timestamp(parsed.getTime())
        case Failure(_) => null
    }

    (id, p_timestamp)
}.toDF("id", "dt").show
```

Output:

```
+---+-------------------+
| id|                 dt|
+---+-------------------+
|  1|2019-01-15 02:24:00|
|  3|1981-01-30 15:11:00|
|  2|               null|
+---+-------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi here is the sample code

```
df.withColumn("times", 
              from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(col("df"), "M/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a"),
              "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS"))
  .show(false)
```